# Como obtener los nombres de los archivos de un directorio? C++

Tags: c++, ogre

Tengo un directorio **media/map**, en esa carpeta hay muchos archivos, ejemplo ".mesh.xml", ".mesh", etc. Necesito crear una funcion que guarde en un array de string los nombres de los archivos ".mesh" e ignore los otros incluido ".mesh.xml".

Aclaración: el array deberia guardar el nombre + el formato, es decir, **ejemplo.mesh**

Para que quiero esto?
Para ahorrarme el trabajo de cargarlos manualmente.

Que tengo hasta ahora?
Algo semi-automatico, simplemente tengo un array de string donde pongo manualmente los nombres de los archivos (actualmente son 58, pero posteriormente la cifra va a superar los 100), y luego este código:

```
  Ogre::SceneNode *auxNode;
  Ogre::Entity *auxEnt;

  for(int i = 0; i<57; i++){
      string nameNode = "SG_Map";
      nameNode+=static_cast<std::ostringstream*>(&(std::ostringstream() << i))->str();
      auxNode = _sceneMgr->createSceneNode(nameNode);
      auxEnt = _sceneMgr->createEntity(myArray[i]);
      auxNode->attachObject(auxEnt);
      _sceneMgr->getRootSceneNode()->addChild(auxNode);
  }
```

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/filesystem/example/simple_ls.cpp

Comment: He visto la primer respuesta a esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140483/how-to-get-list-of-files-with-a-specific-extension-in-a-given-folder después de instalar pude compilar bien, pero no entiende que parámetros debo pasarle y que devuelve, por favor podrías verlo?

Comment: El estándar de C++, hasta C++17 no dispone de ningun mecanismo para interactuar con el sistema de ficheros... para poder realizar esta tarea con estándares anteriores tienes que recurrir a librerías de terceros o a la API del Sistema Operativo. Si no das mas detalles es imposible darte una solución

Comment: En este caso me interesa para linux, aunque podría usar Boost perfectamente, ya instale y compile, pero no entiendo que parámetros debo pasarle a la función que puse en el link mas arriba.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El acceso al sistema de archivos es dependiente de plataforma, así que sin conocer el sistema operativo con el que trabaja sólo te queda usar una librería genérica como [Boost Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), en su [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html) dispones de un ejemplo de cómo recorrer los elementos de una carpeta:

`Boost`

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

void muestra_contenido_de(const std::string &a_carpeta)
{
    boost::filesystem::path p(a_carpeta);

    if (boost::filesystem::exists(p) && boost::filesystem::is_directory(p))
    {
        std::cout << p << " contiene:\n";

        for (auto &x : boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(p))
              cout << "    " << x.path() << '\n'; 
    }
}
```

Si no puedes o no quieres usar Boost, tu código deberá ser dependiente de plataforma, en Windows:

`Windows`

```
#include <windows.h>

void muestra_contenido_de(const std::string &a_carpeta)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd{};

    if (auto handle = FindFirstFile((a_carpeta + "/*.*").c_str(), &ffd))
    {
        do
        {
            std::cout << ffd.cFileName << '\n';
        }
        while (FindNextFile(handle, &ffd) != 0);
    }
}
```

Y aquí para Linux:

`Linux`

```
#include <dirent.h>

void muestra_contenido_de(const std::string &a_carpeta)
{
    if (DIR *dpdf = opendir(a_carpeta.c_str()))
    {
        dirent *epdf = nullptr;
        while (epdf = readdir(dpdf))
        {
            std::cout << epdf->d_name << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Como último apunte, se prevé la aprobación del estándar C++17 para este agosto, este estándar se prevé que incluya una librería estándar de acceso a sistema de archivos, puedes leer los documentos técnicos de dicha propuesta aquí:

- [P0218R0 [image]](http://wg21.link/p0218r0) Adoptar la especificación técnica de sistema de archivos para C++17.
- [P0219R1 [image]](http://wg21.link/p0219r1) Rutas relativas para Sistema de Archivos (Primera revisión).
- [P0317R1 [image]](http://wg21.link/p0317r1) Caché para `directory_entry` (Primera revisión).
- [P0392R0 [image]](http://wg21.link/p0392r0) Las rutas de Sistema de archivos deben adaptar `string_view`.
- [P0430R2 [image]](http://wg21.link/p0430r2) Librería de sistema de archivos en sistemas operativos no POSIX.
- [P0492R2 [image]](http://wg21.link/p0492r2) Resoluciones propuestas a los comentarios del *C++17 National Body* sobre Sistema de Archivos (Segunda revisión).

Esta nueva librería estándar permitirá lo siguiente:

`C++17`

```
#include <filesystem>

void muestra_contenido_de(const std::string &a_carpeta)
{
    for (auto &p : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(a_carpeta))
        std::cout << p << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu excelente respuesta. Como puedo mejorar tu primera función (la de Boost) para que se limite a guardar en un vector solo los archivos con formato ".mesh", luego que retorne ese vector

Comment: @Strelok no he probado el código de Boost, pero lo exploro y edito la pregunta.

Comment: @Strelok Aparentemente Boost no permite recorrer una carpeta filtrando por nombre de archivo, si necesitas una extensión determinada deberás examinar el nombre del archivo detectado.